# Publishing to Sonatype via SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, nexus, sonatype

I am attempting to publish a scala library to the OSS Sonatype repository via SBT. I have followed the SBT guides for Publishing[0](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html) & [Using Sonatype](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Using-Sonatype.html) and reviewed the Sonatype [requirements](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html) documentation, but cannot seem to publish my artifacts. All attempts end with `java.io.IOException: Access to URL [...] was refused by the server: Forbidden`. I have had the necessary repository setup done in the [Sonatype JIRA](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-11092) system. I have created a PGP key and published it to `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net` & `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com`.

`build.sbt`

```
import play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl

name := "spring-mvc-twirl"

organization := "us.hexcoder"

version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

sbtVersion := "0.13.5"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(SbtTwirl)

// Removed for brevity    
libraryDependencies ++= Seq()

// Test dependencies
// Removed for brevity
libraryDependencies ++= Seq()

// Publish configurations
publishMavenStyle := true

publishArtifact in Test := false

publishTo := {
    val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
    if (isSnapshot.value)
        Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
    else
        Some("releases"  at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
}

licenses := Seq("MIT" -> url("http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"))

homepage := Some(url("https://github.com/67726e/Spring-MVC-Twirl"))

credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")

pomIncludeRepository := { _ => false }

// Additional POM information for releases
pomExtra :=
<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Glenn Nelson</name>
        <email>glenn@hexcoder.us</email>
    </developer>
</developers>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:67726e/Spring-MVC-Twirl.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:67726e/Spring-MVC-Twirl.git</developerConnection>
    <url>git@github.com:67726e/Spring-MVC-Twirl.git</url>
</scm>
```

SBT Output:

```
> publishSigned
[info] Wrote /Users/67726e/Documents/Spring-MVC-Twirl/target/scala-2.11/spring-mvc-twirl_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] :: delivering :: us.hexcoder#spring-mvc-twirl_2.11;1.0.0-SNAPSHOT :: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT :: integration :: Tue Aug 19 09:57:13 EDT 2014
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/67726e/Documents/Spring-MVC-Twirl/target/scala-2.11/ivy-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:publishSigned for the full output.
[error] (*:publishSigned) java.io.IOException: Access to URL https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/us/hexcoder/spring-mvc-twirl_2.11/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-mvc-twirl_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar was refused by the server: Forbidden
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Aug 19, 2014 9:57:18 AM
> last *:publishSigned
java.io.IOException: Access to URL https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/us/hexcoder/spring-mvc-twirl_2.11/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-mvc-twirl_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar was refused by the server: Forbidden
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.AbstractURLHandler.validatePutStatusCode(AbstractURLHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.upload(BasicURLHandler.java:264)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:150)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
```

Comment: According to [Sonatype's artifact deployment notes](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/24431007-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Deployment-Failures), you may not have permission to upload to the repository. Has Sonatype resolved your JIRA request to host a project repository?

Comment: As of the time of this comment, it doesn't look like there's a `hexcoder` directory under [https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/us/](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/us/). This might mean that your request hasn't been processed yet.

Comment: @MikeAllen Thanks for taking the time to check out my question... I submitted a ticket with the Sonatype folks and it turns out there was an issue with their internal system and my account was not given the correct permission. As an aside, the `hexcoder` directory was not created until I pushed my snapshot, so I don't think it is created at provisioning time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is one of those rare times as a developer where the issue is not in any way caused by me. I filed a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-11092) on the Sonatype tracker and it turns out there was an with their tooling that caused my account to have not been [granted the correct permissions](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-11092?focusedCommentId=269550&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-269550) during provisioning.

To address @MikeAllen's comments, I had already created a JIRA account and had my repository created by filing a JIRA ticket as a part of their workflow (this was done 5 days prior). The directory corresponding to my domain/group of `hexcoder.us` - `us/hexcoder` was not created until I pushed my first snapshot as seen by the timestamps in the directory browser. It does not appear to be created during repository provisioning.

Finally, I wholly believe that performing one's due diligence is a necessity when it comes to investigating and debugging errors. However do not take it to the extreme as I often do and neglect to ask for assistance from others after a reasonable amount of time has been spent.